# How can I change view mode from view to edit on row click?

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I want to be able to switch a row to edit mode when user clicks on it

I had tried to use the event *userRowSelect*, on my.component.html:

```
<ng2-smart-table 
  class="class-content"
  [settings]="settings" 
  [source]="source"
  (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
  (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)"
  (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"
  (rowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
  (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)"
>
</ng2-smart-table>
```

then in my.component.ts:

```
onUserRowSelect(e) {
    console.log('onUserRowSelect', e);
}
```

with no success

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and finally I found a solution :

From the documentation https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation , there are two events for you : *rowSelect* or *userRowSelect*

We first set a name to our table, then catch the *userRowSelect* action :

```
<ng2-smart-table #table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (userRowSelect)="switchToEdit($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

In our component :

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

...

@ViewChild('table') table: Ng2SmartTableComponent;

...

switchToEdit(event) {
  this.table.grid.getSelectedRows().forEach((row) => {
    this.table.grid.edit(row);
  });
}
```